# Beautifulsoup can't extract data in this website

Tags: python, request, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
f =open('ala2009link.csv','r')
s=open('2009alanews.csv','w')
for row in csv.reader(f):
url=row[0]
print url
res = requests.get(url)
print res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content)
print soup
data=soup.find_all("article",{"class":"article-wrapper news"})
#data=soup.find_all("main",{"class":"main-content"})
for item in data:
    title= item.find_all("h2",{"class","article-headline"})[0].text
    s.write("%s \n"% title)
content=soup.find_all("p")
for main in content:
    k=main.text.encode('utf-8')
    s.write("%s \n"% k)
    #k=csv.writer(s)
    #k.writerow('%s\n'% (main))
s.close()
f.close()
```

this is my code to extract data in website ,but i don't know why i can't extract data ,is this ad blocker warning to block my beautifulsoup ?
[image]
this is the example link:http://www.rolltide.com/news/2009/6/23/Bert_Bank_Passes_Away.aspx?path=football

Comment: What´s the last line in the block of this for loop for row in csv.reader(f)? ANy chance to provide sample html or link?

Comment: Can you provide link ?

Comment: the sample :the sample: http://www.rolltide.com/news/2009/6/23/Bert_Bank_Passes_Away.aspx?path=football @pawelty

Comment: @akashkarothiya the  sample: http://www.rolltide.com/news/2009/6/23/Bert_Bank_Passes_Away.aspx?path=football

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that no results are returned is because this website requires that you have a User-Agent header in your request.

To fix this add a headers parameter with a `User-Agent` to the `requests.get()` like so.

```
url = 'http://www.rolltide.com/news/2009/6/23/Bert_Bank_Passes_Away.aspx?path=football'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/29.0.1547.65 Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36',
    }
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: that's very useful! how did you know that that you needed to pass headers argument as well? Haven-t come across a case like that so far.

Comment: Just a quick test and experience. but to learn you can use fiddler (or another similar software) to capture requests made by the browser and those made by your code and see what the differences are.